# OpsCenter on AWS: No permission to create /mnt/cassandra/data

Tags: datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I installed latest OpsCenter (v5.0.0, through AMI 3cf7c979), found [here](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/install/installAMILaunch.html)) on EC2 m3.large. When adding new nodes through the admin interface (port 8888), I get this error:

**Error: Start stage failed: Failed to start node [ip]: Timed out waiting for Cassandra to start.**

The log on the individual server is:

```
CassandraDaemon.java (line 235) Directory /mnt/cassandra/data doesn't exist
CassandraDaemon.java (line 239) Has no permission to create /mnt/cassandra/data directory
```

How come new nodes don't have the permissions to create the /mnt/cassandra dir?

I generated a key/secret with all permissions for the "Amazon EC2 Credentials".

If I manually SSH every new instance, create the /mnt/cassandra dir, chown it and restart the service - it works. I expected it to happen automatically.

Comment: Could you describe your environment and steps in a bit more detail? What version of OpsCenter are you using? When launching a Cassandra instance, are you using OpsCenter’s Cloud Provisioning?

Comment: @arre, I edited parts of the answer: latest version (2.5.1), launching nodes through the admin interface of OpsCenter.

Comment: I believe you're looking at the community AMI for version 2.5.1? Did you launch via the EC2 management console as opposed to opscenter (the current version being 5.0.0).  Can you confirm in the ec2 management for the machine there should be an ami ID, can you specify that #?

Comment: @Dio - The AMI is "DataStax Auto-Clustering AMI 2.5.1-hvm - ami-3cf7c979 ", the OpsCenter is v5.0.0. (Updated question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up ditching the AMI. It was probably not up-to-date. I installed opscenter with apt-get on a fresh ubuntu machine and everything worked great.

Answer (score 1):

Opscenter 5.0.0 is configured with a default AMI version.  When you attempt a cloud provision via the UI, you'll see an AMI version is already specified.  This is the version to use with opscenter.  There are newer AMIs (such as the versions you linked) but as yet they are not fully supported in opscenter, which is why there is an issue with provisioning when you attempt to use them.

With the document you linked, that is instructions for using AMIs via the EC2 console.  That is a different provisioning experience than when you provision via opscenter.  This is the difference you are experiencing.

As a future improvement to opscenter, I think possibly changing that field from a text box to a drop down to make it clear which AMIs are supported might clarify this sort of problem.

Comment: Thanks. I restarted the process with ami-32f7c977 (PV us-west-1), and specified that AMI in the Node Nodes modal now. I get a new error: `Install Errored: Lost track of the request`. The new node has Cassandra installed, but its `seeds` (on cassandra.yml) isn't pointing to the OpsCenter instance. Both nodes are on the generated OpsCenterSecurityGroup security group and accessible to each other.

Comment: The `seeds` of the new node points to itself. Doesn't seem like the `cassandra.yml` was initialized properly. The data_file_dir points to `/raid0/cassandra/data` and not `/mnt/cassandra/..`, and the `/mnt/` doesn't exist again.

Comment: Hi @elado stack overflow gets very angry when I answer multiple questions in the same reply, they like to have one question per post (trust me, they deleted my answer the last time I answered multiple questions).  As a very quick answer, the seeds should only have nodes, not opscenter (unless you installed opscenter on the same box as a node, which is not recommended) for further reading please check here: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_qfg_n1r_1k__seed_provider I'm out of space, please ask new quest.